# How to set value to model from json using custom annotations processing in java

Tags: java, json, annotations

If I have an `Animal` model that is-

```
@MyModel(name="animal")
class Animal {
    @MyField(name="id")
    int id;
    @MyField(name="name")
    String name;
    @MyField(name="weight")
    String weight;

    public Animal(){
    }
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setName(int name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.idname
    }
    public void setWeight(int weight){
        this.weight=weight;
    }
    public int getWeight(){
        return this.weight;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Animal={id="+id+", name="+name+", weight="+weight+"}";
    }
}
```

and I have a `JSON` like this-

```
{"id":1, "name": "Cat", "weight": "1kg"}
```

and `Type` `annotation` is like-

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyModel {
    String name() default "";
}
```

and `Field` `annotation` is like-

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyField {
    String name() default "";
}
```

How do I process this `annotation` and set the value of `JSON` to `model` without using any third-party library?

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to write your own annotation processors for the annotations. You can start reading about that from here: http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101 it will help in understanding the basics.

Comment: You can also trace the source code to learn how those 3-rd party libraries to do that such as `Jackson`: [jackson-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations).

Comment: Sorry LHCNIN, as per requirements, we can't use a third-party library.